# When I change display to "none" and "block", my title repositions rather than disappearing and reappearing where it originally was

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I have it set so that when you click start, it will hide the main page and then make it reappear, although it will be in a different location. I'm not sure if the issue is within the html, css, or javscript as I'm pretty new to all of this. Supposedly, I need more words for this post to post, so I'm going to just fill the rest of this section with a bunch of meaningless words.

Here is a preview: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/holychickencow/A-Fair-Game/blob/main/index.html
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Play&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>A Fair Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main" id="mainPage">
        <h1 id="title">A Fair Game</h1>
        <button onclick="startGame()" id="start">Start</button>
        <div class="bottom">
            <button onclick="openHow()">How to Play</button>
            <button onclick="openSettings()">Settings</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="settings" id="settingsPage" hidden>
        <button onclick="openMain()">Back</button>
    </div>

    <div class="how" id="howPage" hidden>
        <button onclick="openMain()">Back</button>
    </div>

    <script src="afg.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
}

.main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

#title{
    font-size: 300%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.bottom{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

button{
    padding: 20px 100px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin: 40px;
    border-color: #03e9f4;
    color: #03e9f4;
    transition: 0.5s;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

#start{
    padding: 40px 200px;
}

button:hover{
    background: #03e9f4;
    color: #050801;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
                0 0 5px #03e9f4,
                0 0 25px #03e9f4,
                0 0 100px #03e9f4;
     -webkit-box-reflect:below 1px linear-gradient(transparent, #0005);
}
```

Javscript:

```
function openSettings(){
    document.getElementById("mainPage").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("settingsPage").style.display = "block";
}

function openHow(){
    document.getElementById("mainPage").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("howPage").style.display = "block";
}

function openMain(){
    if(document.getElementById("settingsPage").style.display == "block"){
        document.getElementById("settingsPage").style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("howPage").style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("mainPage").style.display = "block";
}

function startGame(){
    document.getElementById("mainPage").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("mainPage").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you set `display` for main in CSS as `flex` and then in js you set it to `block`.

the other problem is that in `startGame()` function, you need to set a condition for each execution. because in the way you write it, it will go `none` then `flex`.

I used this condition to hide mainPage.

```
function startGame(){
    var mainPage = document.getElementById("mainPage");
    if (mainPage.display = "flex") {
        document.getElementById("mainPage").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mainPage").style.display = "flex";
}
    }
```

I hope this will help you understand how to set things better. good luck.